# files are not visible in gitlab project

Tags: git, gitlab

I am trying to move local directory on gitlab repository. I follow the steps as:

1. Create an empty project on gitlab
2. git init in directory which I want to connect as remote and run "git remote add origin [https://gitlab.com/govindIITD/pof.git"](https://gitlab.com/govindIITD/pof.git%22)
3. git add .
4. git commit -m "Ist commit"
5. git push -u origin master

I do not get any error while doing this except I am giving username and password explicitly.

After doing this, I do not find the files which are committed.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Govind

Comment: What did it print after you ran `git push -u origin master` and input the username and password?

Comment: What is output of `git remote -v`

Comment: If you recently create a project on GitLab.com, the [default branch](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/branches/default.html) name is `main` instead of `master` (since GitLab 14.0) - unless you specify it otherwise in your repository settings. If you're trying to view your repository at `https://gitlab.com/govindIITD/pof`, your `main` branch is probably empty. Try to see if you can see your files at `https://gitlab.com/govindIITD/pof/-/tree/master`.

Comment: Thanks @lyzlisa.  Yes I can look at commits in tree/master. I need to make changes in default settings.

Comment: @Manoj: git remote -v works fine. By the way I got the problem Thanks.

Comment: @ElpieKay , yes I was on default settings i.e. main. Now I understood. Thanks.